# Strange Highlighting Color In ZSH Menu

Tags: zsh, colors, autocomplete

I am using Arch Linux and `zsh`.

When selecting options from a menu in `zsh` the color appears to be off when moving down in the list. For example after pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key twice after typing `cd` results in the following as expected:

[image: Normal behavior]

Now the strange thing is when I move down in the menu the option is gray:

[image: Abnormal behavior]

If I approach that menu item from any other direction (for instance from the right side moving left -- moving over from music) the menu option is normal again:

[image: Side behavior]

Although not a giant problem, it is kind of bothersome. Why is this happening and is there a fix?

**.zshrc**

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/home/carloabelli/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="carloabelli"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=7

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
HIST_STAMPS="yyyy-mm-dd"

setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
HISTFILE=~/.zsh-history

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(archlinux catimg command-not-found common-aliases encode64 gem git git-extras jsontools lol man python rand-quote ruby sudo systemd vundle)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# You may need to manually set your language environment
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi
export EDITOR='vim'

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/id_rsa"

# Automatically rehash completion
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true

# Syntax highlighting
source /usr/share/zsh/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

compdef gpg2=gpg

alias ls='ls -FGh --color=auto'
alias la='ls -a'
alias lla='la -l'
alias lal='lla'
```

**carloabelli.zsh-theme**

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=" %{$fg_bold[blue]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %{$fg_bold[red]%}✘"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=" %{$fg_bold[green]%}✔"

PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%~$(git_prompt_info) %(?.%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%})»%{$reset_color%} '
```

Comment: Post your `.zshrc` (and any file that it sources).

Comment: @Gilles Done. I am using `oh-my-zsh` which of course gets sourced, but I am not going to include it all here.